# Java run time error reported on running an application using Contiki_OS in Linux

Tags: java, openjdk

I got the following error on compiling and executing an application in Contiki-NG using the Virtual Machine in Linux Ubuntu 16.04.06, 
The simulator stops around 1.4 seconds with a message given below:
……………………………………………………………………………………………………………..
**[java] A fatal error has been detected by the java runtime environment:
[java]  SIGSEGV
[java] Java Result:139**
……………………………………………………………………………………………………………..
This **code** was running perfectly but now I am unable to run my application written in Contiki OS.
Linux: Ubuntu 16.04

Java Version
openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-8u242-b08-0ubuntu3~16.04-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)

Kindly help me.

Martin

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have written JNI modules, getting a SIGSEGV is a bug, so you have to update your Java runtime.

You appear to be running the official openjdk from Ubuntu 16.04, so I doubt it will be updated (it almost the last update to OpenJDK8 anyway), given that 16.04 is EOL. OpenJDK 8 is also in its last year (supports ends in December 2020).

You best bet right now it to replace JDK8 with JDK9 which is also available in 16.04, (both should coexist on the same system, see the `alternatives` command). You could have your problem fixed in 10 minutes or so.

This said even Java9 is getting ancient, if you have to change versions you can get something more modern...